# Conversion of median calculation from MySQL to SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, t-sql, median

I'm trying to convert this median calculation in MySQL to SQL Server.

http://danielsetzermann.com/howto/how-to-calculate-the-median-per-group-with-mysql/

Here is the code:

```sql
SET @row_number:=0; 
SET @median_group:='';

SELECT 
    median_group, AVG(height) AS median
FROM
    (SELECT
        @row_number:=
            CASE
            WHEN @median_group = gender THEN @row_number + 1
            ELSE 1
            END AS count_of_group,
        @median_group:=gender AS median_group,
        gender,
        height,
        (SELECT 
            COUNT(*)
        FROM heights
        WHERE a.gender = gender)
        AS total_of_group
    FROM
        (SELECT 
            gender,
            height
        FROM heights
        ORDER BY gender, height)
        AS a)
    AS b
    WHERE
        count_of_group BETWEEN total_of_group / 2.0 AND total_of_group / 2.0 + 1
GROUP BY median_group
```

This is as far as I got:

```sql
DECLARE @row_number integer, @median_group varchar(100)
SET @row_number = 0
SET @median_group = ''

SELECT
  @row_number = (CASE WHEN @median_group = gender THEN @row_number + 1 ELSE 1 END) AS count_of_group,
  (@median_group = gender) AS median_group,
  gender,
  height,
  (SELECT COUNT(*)
   FROM heights
   WHERE a.gender = gender)
   AS total_of_group
FROM
  (SELECT
     gender,
     height
  FROM heights)
  AS a
ORDER BY a.gender , a.height
```

Sadly I don't know how to get past this error:

> A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval operations.

I know there are a few other ways to calculate median that are SQL Server specific, but not knowing how to make this conversion is eating at me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would you convert that code when you can do something like this?

```
select distinct gender, percentile_cont(0.5) over (partition by gender order by height)
from heights;
```

SQL Server has many other approaches for such a calculation.

Comment: thanks for the response. I came from the mysql world and now learning mssql. The mysql solution was something that I understood and have used in the past.
Eventually I learned of multiple sql server solutions, but it still bugged me that I couldn't convert it. So this is more of a learning experience on the difference btw mysql and sql server]

Comment: @BayoO'liliJason' . . . MySQL (prior to version 8) is not a very good introduction to ANSI SQL and the capabilities of other databases for querying purposes.